# Physics problem - floating object

Tags: physics

[image]

I am testing cloth physics.
But I have some problem.
Why my object is floating in the air?
Could you tell me how I can fix this please?

Comment: can you show us your blend file?

Comment: Here it is : http://bigfile.mail.naver.com/bigfileupload/download?fid=9sFvp6RqM6dZKq2jK3YZFqbqa3YZKAUmKxuZKoUqFAgqFwYwFog/FotlKxvlHqMZazu9KqMZKqICpAumaxMwF6FCpAuXMotXMo04KzF4